# Conversion from string error

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm trying to show an error if one of the statement is false, but I get an error: "**Conversion from string "False\example.exe**" **to type** '**Boolean' is not valid.**"

```
If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE", "InstallLocation", "") <> "" And
        My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE", "InstallLocation", "ERROR")) & "\example.exe" Then
    Else
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        example_error.ShowDialog()
    End If
```

EDIT:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ExecutablePath = IO.Path.Combine(CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MYAPP", "InstallLocation", "ERROR")), "myapp.exe")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MYAPP", "InstallLocation", ""))) _
        AndAlso My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(ExecutablePath) Then
    Else
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        GUI_Error.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "\example.exe" is outside of the exists() call, it needs to go inside the parentheses

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't help " My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE", "InstallLocation", "ERROR" & "\example.exe")) Then"

Answer (score 1):

Your second condition is incorrect since you want to concatenate a path with the filename and use `FileSystem.Exists` to check if the file exists, but the filename is not inside of the method-call. Instead of concatenating string to create a path you should use `Path.Combine`:

```
Dim filePath = Path.Combine(CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE", "InstallLocation", "ERROR")),
                            "example.exe")
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\EXAMPLE", "InstallLocation", ""))) _
    AndAlso File.Exists(filePath) Then
Else
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    example_error.ShowDialog()
End If
```

Comment: Many thanks Tim but now when I try to change registry key I get another error instead of that custom dialog

"Value cannot be null."
"Parameter name: path1."

Comment: Then you have to show the code. Are you sure that that error is related to this issue? If it's not related you should ask another question.

Comment: @VeilSide: I assume that you get the error in `Path.Combine` since the  first part of the path is null which means that `My.Computer.Registry.GetValue` returned null. If that's the case(use the debugger to inspect the value) then you should ask another question. I'm not familiar with this method and your registry, it's a different question anyway.